# problems using atmega644pv jtag pins as gpio

Tags: avr, gpio, jtag

I've been trying to use port C pins on an atmega644pv as gpio, and have been running into some trouble. as far as i can discern, it seems like the middle four pins (PORTC 2,3,4,5) are stuck in a high impedance state (used a screwdriver to short them the outer four pins, and the later mentioned leds behaved as desired). digging a bit it looks like these are the JTAG pins, but i disabled JTAG via the fuse bits. the code below (should) make the attached leds light up sequentially, sort of like a cylon/knight rider project but only going in one direction, but when i run it the four middle leds only light dimly, whereas the outer ones hit full brightness. for reference, the leds are attached between PORTA and PORTC, and have a resistor series with them on the PORTA side. I can't use only PORTA and ground, because i need to reverse bias the leds in my actual code, and then monitor their voltage.

-U lfuse:w:0x62:m -U hfuse:w:0xd9:m -U efuse:w:0xff:m

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int setup(void)
{

    DDRD = 0x7F;
    MCUCR |= (1 << PUD);
MCUCR |= (1<<JTD);
PORTD=0x00;
DDRC=0xFF;
DDRA=0xFF;

}

int main(void)
{
DDRA=0xFF;
DDRC=0xFF;
PORTA=0x00;
    PORTC=0xFF;
    while(1){
    if (PIND&0x80){
        PORTC=0xFF;
        PORTA=(0b11111110);
        _delay_ms(10);
        PORTA=0b11111101;
        _delay_ms(10);
        PORTA=~0b00000100;
        _delay_ms(10);
        PORTA=~0b00001000;
        _delay_ms(10);
        PORTA=~0b00010000;
        _delay_ms(10);
        PORTA=~0b00100000;
        _delay_ms(10);
        PORTA=~0b01000000;
        _delay_ms(10);
        PORTA=~0b10000000;
        _delay_ms(10);
        PORTA=~0b00000000;
    }
    else{
    _delay_ms(10);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

many thanks!

EDIT: forgot to call setup() at the beginning of main()  =(
more coffee was required

Comment: Even though it sounds fairly simple it might be worth adding a schematic including the resistor values. I wonder if you're exceeding one of the port-wide maximum current draws at the stage you have multiple LEDs on?

Comment: thanks for the thought, but i do not believe that's the case, as they don't hit full brightness even when i tell only one of them to turn on at a time. when the code initializes, all of the leds should light up, and they do, but the middle ones are very dim. when the scan is executing, only one led is ever lit at a time, with the middle four leds only ever turning on in the dim state. fwiw: 200 Ohms for all of the series resistors.

Comment: also, the thing i also meant to say but didn't is that a clone of the code that initalizes all of the leds in the off state (i.e. never more than one led on at a time) exhibits the same symptoms.

Comment: Its sounding like you now have some control over the pins.  Are you sure the JTAG pins have the same rated drive strength as others?  I've seen MCU's from other vendors where they did not, and LEDs can be fairly heavy loads for direct drive from an MCU pin.

Comment: the datasheet indicated that in their output functionality, ports A and C had symmetric driving characteristics across the port, with high current sink and source ability. again, the first two and last two pins in the port drive the led brightly, and the issue persists even with code that only lights one led at a time. thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 8.10.7 in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2593.pdf) lists the following ways to disable JTAG

- Disable the OCDEN Fuse.
- Disable the JTAGEN Fuse.
- Write one to the JTD bit in MCUCR.

You say you have disabled JTAG from the fuses but just in case, can you add the following at the start of main (or setup)

```
MCUCR |=(1<<JTD);
MCUCR |=(1<<JTD);
```

The JTD bit needs to be written twice :

> In order to avoid unintentional disabling or enabling of the JTAG interface, a timed sequence must be followed when changing this bit: The application software must write this bit to the desired value twice within four cycles to change its value.

---

I noticed that you have already included the following in setup()

```
MCUCR |= (1<<JTD);
```

but a single write will not have any effect as I explained above

---

Adding to what Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams wrote in the comments, you may run into trouble with the read-modify-write operation as opposed to a write only operation.

(using avrgcc)

### READ/MODIFY/WRITE

with Os,O3,O2 optimization level the read/modify/write you get a code which is barely within the 4 cycle limit but will work:

```
    MCUCR |= (1 << JTD);
  88:   85 b7           in  r24, 0x35   ; 53
  8a:   80 68           ori r24, 0x80   ; 128
  8c:   85 bf           out 0x35, r24   ; 53
    MCUCR |= (1 << JTD);
  8e:   85 b7           in  r24, 0x35   ; 53
  90:   80 68           ori r24, 0x80   ; 128
  92:   85 bf           out 0x35, r24   ; 53
```

With O1 optimization level you get a code which will not work (7 cycle between writes):

```
    MCUCR |= (1 << JTD);
  94:   e5 e5           ldi r30, 0x55   ; 85
  96:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
  98:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
  9a:   80 68           ori r24, 0x80   ; 128
  9c:   80 83           st  Z, r24
    MCUCR |= (1 << JTD);
  9e:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
  a0:   80 68           ori r24, 0x80   ; 128
  a2:   80 83           st  Z, r24
  a4:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2         ; 0xa4 <main+0x10>
```

With O0 (optimization off) you get a code which is way off from the 4 cycle limit:

```
    MCUCR |= (1 << JTD);
  90:   a5 e5           ldi r26, 0x55   ; 85
  92:   b0 e0           ldi r27, 0x00   ; 0
  94:   e5 e5           ldi r30, 0x55   ; 85
  96:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
  98:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
  9a:   80 68           ori r24, 0x80   ; 128
  9c:   8c 93           st  X, r24
    MCUCR |= (1 << JTD);
  9e:   a5 e5           ldi r26, 0x55   ; 85
  a0:   b0 e0           ldi r27, 0x00   ; 0
  a2:   e5 e5           ldi r30, 0x55   ; 85
  a4:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
  a6:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
  a8:   80 68           ori r24, 0x80   ; 128
  aa:   8c 93           st  X, r24
  ac:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2         ; 0xac <main+0x24>
```

### WRITE

A better approach is to just use a write operation that will work fine with any optimization level (Os,O1,O2,O3) **but not** when you disable optimization (O0)

Using Os, O3, O2

```
    MCUCR = (1 << JTD);
  88:   80 e8           ldi r24, 0x80   ; 128
  8a:   85 bf           out 0x35, r24   ; 53
    MCUCR = (1 << JTD);
  8c:   85 bf           out 0x35, r24   ; 53
```

Using O1

```
    MCUCR = (1 << JTD);
  94:   e5 e5           ldi r30, 0x55   ; 85
  96:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
  98:   80 e8           ldi r24, 0x80   ; 128
  9a:   80 83           st  Z, r24
    MCUCR = (1 << JTD);
  9c:   80 83           st  Z, r24
```

Using O0

```
  MCUCR = (1 << JTD);
  9c:   e5 e5           ldi r30, 0x55   ; 85
  9e:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
  a0:   80 e8           ldi r24, 0x80   ; 128
  a2:   80 83           st  Z, r24
    MCUCR = (1 << JTD);
  a4:   e5 e5           ldi r30, 0x55   ; 85
  a6:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
  a8:   80 e8           ldi r24, 0x80   ; 128
  aa:   80 83           st  Z, r24
```

Comment: And you may actually have to store the value of a bit shift in a local variable and copy from that local variable twice in order to make it work under all optimization levels. [Example here (at the beginning of `main()`)](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33883/embedded-conditional-code-compaction).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams updated post

Comment: have tried the following:  
    #include <avr/io.h>
    #include <util/delay.h>
    int a = (1 << JTD);

    int setup(void)
    {
     MCUCR = a;
     MCUCR = a;
     MCUCR |= (1 << PUD);  

as well as calling:  
    MCUCR = (1<<JTD);
    MCUCR = (1<<JTD);

and also the same idea using |=   
Os is on   
issue is persistent  
thanks for the help sofar!

Comment: also, have used the method outlined in the beginning of main() that was linked, problem persistent

Comment: @user36304 does this mean that you managed to solve the problem or gave up on it? In case you didn't solve the  problem I have no other explanation, whenever I faced a problem regarding JTAG I/O port pins in AVR it was always related to the JTAG not being turned off.

Comment: solved it, as stated above, i forgot to call "setup()"
because tired